# c++ calling function which is member of class

Tags: c++, class, oop

I would like to call a function hi() in main() which is a member of the class myclass

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
    private:
    //none 

    public:
        void hi ();
};

void myclass::hi()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world!"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    hi();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
/home/michael/Escritorio/deal/examples/stepup/stepup.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/michael/Escritorio/deal/examples/stepup/stepup.cc:24:12: error: ‘hi’ was not declared in this scope
     hi();
```

I also tried

```
myclass::hi();
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try creating `myclass` instance, and calling the method `hi` on that?

Comment: Like doing myclass.hi() ?

Comment: Better still: `myclass obj; obj.hi();`.

Comment: Even if you want to call hi function without class object, declare function as static and call funciton as myclass::hi().

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate the myclass first in the main function like

```
myclass georg;
```

and then you have to write `georg.hi();` then it'll work.

Comment: Technically, the term `initialise the myclass` is not correct. You are creating an instance of the class. When you are writing `int a;` you are not saying that you are initializing `int`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks

Comment: /home/michael/Escritorio/deal/examples/stepup/stepup.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/michael/Escritorio/deal/examples/stepup/stepup.cc:25:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
         myclass.hi();
                ^
/home/michael/Escritorio/deal/examples/stepup/stepup.cc:24:17: warning: unused variable ‘hi’ [-Wunused-variable]
         myclass hi;

Comment: Seems like you are trying myclass.hi(). That is obviously wrong. Try my solution it works perfectly.